# ObjectMapper configuration with write xml 1.1 for invalid xml characters

Tags: java, xml, jackson

I have written code to serialize and to read serialize json which is throwing error for particular xml where which have &#26
IllegalArgumentException: Failed to parse JSON String as XML: Character reference "&#26" is an invalid XML character.

```
    SampleClass input;
    ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ObjectMapper mapperInput = new ObjectMapper();
    mapperInput.setSerializationInclusion(Include.NON_NULL);
    mapperInput.writeValue(out, input);
    ByteBuffer binary = ByteBuffer.wrap(out.toByteArray());

    ObjectMapper mapperOutput = new ObjectMapper();
    mapperOutput.configure(JsonReadFeature.ALLOW_UNESCAPED_CONTROL_CHARS.mappedFeature(), true);
    mapperOutput.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
    SampleClass output = mapperOutput.readValue(binary.array(), SampleClass.class);
```

SampleClass have some string value and some xmlDocuments. When xml document have "&#26", readvalue throws invalid XML error.

IS there any way to esc invalid character. Which is default xml version? How to set
xmlMapper.configure(ToXmlGenerator.Feature.WRITE_XML_1_1, true); to ObjectMapper?

Comment: I don't get your question. You've written something to read/write JSON and wonder why it fails with XML?

Comment: Here, for sample I added inline code, but actual implementation have public class SampleClassSerializer implements Serializer<SampleClass> where Override serialize have writeValue and Override equal have readValue. I am preparing list and fetching it for further use.